# Button components inside ButtonGroup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React 16.9.0 and Material-UI 4.4.2 and I'm having the following issue.

I want to render a ButtonGroup with Button elements inside it but these buttons come from other custom components which return a Button render with a Modal view linked to the button. Thing is, I can't make them look like a ButtonGroup with the same style since it seems like the Button elements only take the "grouping" styling but not the "visual" styling.

Example code to reproduce behaviour:

```
<ButtonGroup variant="outlined">
    <AModal/>
    <BModal/>
    <CModal/>
</ButtonGroup>
```

[image: Output]

As you can see, the render output does not look as expected. Bare in mind that I'm defining the buttons with the `outlined` variant since if not they just render as Text Buttons.

Any help is much appreciated

Adding `AModal` as requested:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';
import InnerModalComponent from './InnerModalComponent';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    modal: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    paper: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        border: '2px solid #000',
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
        padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
    },
}));

export default function AModal() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    function handleOpen() {
        setOpen(true);
    }

    function handleClose() {
        setOpen(false);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleOpen}> A </Button>
            <Modal
                aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
                aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
                className={classes.modal}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                closeAfterTransition
                BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
                BackdropProps={{ timeout: 500 }}
            >
                <Fade in={open}>
                    <div className={classes.paper}>
                        <div
                            style={{
                                display: 'flex',
                                flexDirection: 'row',
                                alignItems: 'stretch',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                            }}
                        >
                            <InnerModalComponent/>
                        </div>
                        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}> Button inside Modal</Button>
                    </div>
                </Fade>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `variant="outlined"` is the default, no need to explicitely apply. Consider posting `AModal` component.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two main issues:

1. You are adding a `div` around each of your buttons. This will interfere a little with the styling. Change this to a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) (e.g. `<>` or `<React.Fragment>`) instead.
2. The way that `ButtonGroup` works is by [cloning the child `Button` elements](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.4.2/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonGroup/ButtonGroup.js#L136) and adding props to control the styling. When you introduce a custom component in between, you need to pass through to the `Button` any props not used by your custom component.

Here is a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import ButtonGroup from "@material-ui/core/ButtonGroup";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Modal from "@material-ui/core/Modal";

const AModal = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <Button {...props}>A</Button>
      <Modal open={false}>
        <div>Hello Modal</div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
const OtherModal = ({ buttonText, ...other }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Button {...other}>{buttonText}</Button>
      <Modal open={false}>
        <div>Hello Modal</div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
// I don't recommend this approach due to maintainability issues,
// but if you have a lint rule that disallows prop spreading, this is a workaround.
const AvoidPropSpread = ({
  className,
  disabled,
  color,
  disableFocusRipple,
  disableRipple,
  fullWidth,
  size,
  variant
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        className={className}
        disabled={disabled}
        color={color}
        disableFocusRipple={disableFocusRipple}
        disableRipple={disableRipple}
        fullWidth={fullWidth}
        size={size}
        variant={variant}
      >
        C
      </Button>
      <Modal open={false}>
        <div>Hello Modal</div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
function App() {
  return (
    <ButtonGroup>
      <AModal />
      <OtherModal buttonText="B" />
      <AvoidPropSpread />
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit ButtonGroup with Modals]

Comment: Hi @ryan, the solution you provided works like a charm! But I have the following issue: I'm using a linter rule that forbids the usage of prop spreading. Is there any workaround for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Get rid of that linter rule is my advice. You could explicitly pass through each of the individual props, but it would be susceptible to breaking if Material-UI changes what props it passes down. Button C now shows this approach in my example.

Comment: Yup, not really convenient to pass each prop and then use them in the component. Will do as suggested, thanks!

Comment: Point 2) really helped me. How did you figure that out @RyanCogswell ? Did you just come across this problem yourself and look at the source, or was it documented somewhere? Thanks mate!

Comment: @XavierTaylor I figured it out by looking through the source code. I frequently look through the MUI source code when answering StackOverflow questions.

Comment: Thanks @RyanCogswell - people like you are what makes this resource so great!